# Basic htaccess rewrite rule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wasted an entire morning trying to do something very simple.

I have a local server set up with WampServer. The rewrite module is ON in httpd.conf. I want to have something like

```
http://localhost/wordpress/assets/whatever.jpg`
```

point to

```
http://localhost/wordpress/assets/test/whatever.jpg`.
```

I have tried so many variations it is stupid, and I either get no effect, or a redirect loop, or a server error or a message saying that the file can't be found at a location I don't want it to be found at. How about this version, why doesn't this work?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /wordpress/assets/
RewriteRule (.*) test/$1
```

It causes an internal server error. This one gets pretty close, it gets to the test directory but not the jpg:

```
RewriteRule . test/
```

EDIT: oh, I meant to say that this .htaccess file is in the assets folder. I tried things higher up as well. I thought rewriting wasn't happening at all until I figured out the RewriteBase thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're not already rewrite the `test` folder. The rewrite engine loops so the second time around it'll get rewritten again. So something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /wordpress/assets/
RewriteCond $1 !^test/
RewriteRule (.*) test/$1
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /wordpress/assets/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress/assets/test/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) test/$1
```

Comment: @Moss the first makes sure that it's not rewritting a URI that already starts with "test", to prevent the rewriting to URIs like `/wordpress/assets/test/test/test/test/test/test/image.jpg` etc. The second first checks that what it is rewriting to is a file that actually exists, so if `/wordpress/assets/test/image.jpg` exists, it will rewrite, otherwise it does nothing. The side effect is that you'd stop looping and a bonus of getting 404 messages that doesn't say `test` in it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it makes sense. Unfortunately now I tried it again on a different server setup (Bitnami Wordpress instead of WampServer) and now it just shows a WP "Not Found" page...